# An equality relation for complex numbers off the nonnegative real axis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, nonnegative-matrices

For every complex number $z$ off the nonnegative real axis there exist positive numbers $p_0,... ,p_n$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^n p_iz^i = 0$.

Finding difficulty in proceeding with the problem. Need some hints.

Comment: King of strange a question: given a complex number $z$, you can always find a polynomial $P_z$ such that $P(z)=0$, taking e.g. $P_z(X)=X-z$. If you want to impose a degree $n$, take $P_z(X)=(X-z) Q(X)$, where $Q$ is any polynomial with degree $n-1$.

Comment: @Bazin But the problem requires the polynomial $P$ to have nonnegative coefficients.

Comment: Do you want the coefficients $p_i$ to all be positive, or only non-negative?

Comment: @HarryRichman I want the coefficients to be positive

Comment: Some additional context could give support to reopening the question.

Comment: I also mean that no additional context is maybe also support to not reopening the question...!

Answer (score 8):

If $z$ is in the left half plane, there is a quadratic polynomial with non-negative coefficients which has $z$ as a root. If $z$ is not in the left half plane, first find $n$ such that $z^n$ is in the left half plane, then choose a quadratic polynomial in $z^n$.

Comment: How can we prove the first statement?

Comment: @user8795 Use the fact that $z+\overline z=z+|z|z^{-1}$ is real.

Answer (score 5):

It can be rephrased as, is every complex number other than a nonnegative real the root of a polynomial with only nonnegative coefficients?

The answer is yes. Consider $P_n:= (1+x)^n Q$ where $Q $ is a monic nonnegative real quadratic polynomial whose roots are not real (so that they are necessarily complex conjugates of each other); there exists $n$ st $P_n$ has only nonnegative (in fact, strictly positive) coefficients (this is a consequence of a result due to Poincaré before he became famous). If $z$ is not real, such a $Q$ exists with $Q(z) = 0$; if $r$ is a negative real, then obviously $x-r$ works.

We even have that if $n$ is sufficiently large, then the distribution of coefficients of $P_n$ is log concave (strongly unimodal). And obviously, there is no uniform degree that will work for all nonreal $z$.

To provide a sort of qualitative response to the query of Geoffrey Irving, as the argument of $z$ tends to zero, the minimal $n$ goes to infinity (true for the three possible versions of the problem, nonnegative coefficients, no gaps in the coefficients and nonnegative, and nonnegative and log concave). More can be said, but not in this space.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a plot of which regions require which degree.

Comment: What is the actual result you attribute to Poincare?

Comment: The Poincaré result is that if $f \in {\bf R}[x]$ (a real polynomial) such that $f > 0$ on the positive reals, then there exists $n$ such that $(1+x)^n f$ has no negative coefficients. I can't find the reference at the moment, but it appeared in 1883, in *Comptes Rendus*.

Comment: OK, here is the reference: H Poincaré, *Sur les équations algébriques,* CR Acad Sci Paris 97 (1883) 1418.